# How do I use multiple .mo files simultaneously for gettext translation?

Tags: python, plugins, internationalization, gettext

In short, can I use in python many `.mo` files for the same language in the same time?

In my python application, I need to use `gettext` for I18N. This app uses kind of a plug-in system. This means you can download a plug-in and put it in the appropriate directory, and it runs like any other python package. The main application stores the `.mo` file it uses in let's say `./locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/main.mo`. And the plug-in nr 1 has its own `.mo` file called `plugin1.mo` in that same directory.

I would use this to load the `main.mo` I18N messages:

```
gettext.install('main', './locale', unicode=False)
```

How can I install the others too, so that all the plug-ins are translated the way they should be?

The solutions I thought of:

Should I `gettext.install()` in each package's namespace? But this would override the `_()` defined previously and mess the future translations of the main application.

Is there a way to combine two `.mo` files in one (when a new plug-in is installed for example)?

At runtime can I combine them into one `GNUTranslation` object? Or override the default `_()` method that is added to the global namespace? Then, how would I go with that option?
Instead of `_('Hello World')`, I would use `_('plugin1', 'Hello World in plug-in 1')`

Note: The application is not supposed to be aware of all the plug-ins to be installed, so it cannot already have all the messages translated in its `main.mo` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different *domains* for each plugin. The domain can be package name to prevent conflicts.

I do not understand why you need to translate something outside the plugin by using plugin's domain, but if you really need to, then you should disambiguate the domain each time.

Each plugin can provide it's own "undescore", readily bound to the plugin's domain:

```
from my.plugin import MessageFactory as _my_plugin
```

Please, note, that underscore is only a convention so the extraction tools can find i18n-enabled messages in the program. Plugins' messages should be marked with underscore in their respective packages (you do put them into separate packages, right?). In all other places, you are free to call these factories by some other name and leave underscore for the main program translation domain.

I am less sure about .mo-files, but you can surely compile all your .po files into one .mo file. However, if plugins are written by independent uncooperative authors, there could be msgid conflicts.

UPDATE:

If plugins are in the same package with the main app, then there is no sense in using individual translation domains for them (this is not your case). If plugins are in the separate packages, then extraction should be done independently for those packages. In both cases you have no problem with variable _. If for some reason main app wants plugins' translations in its code, use some other name for _, as in the answer. Of course, extraction tools will not identify anything but underscore.

In other words, plugins should care about their translations on their own. The main app could use plugin-specific translation function as part of plug-in API. Extraction or manual addition of strings into po/mo-files are also not of concern for the main app: its up to plugin author to provide translations.

Comment: So you are saying I don't use the _ shortcut for other than the main application, and in the plugins, i would use:
`plugin_translation = gettext.translation('plugins.plugin1', locale_dir)
plugin_translation('text to be translated')
`
like it is suggested in the docs, but will they be identified by the extraction tools as i18n-enabled messages or do i have to call that variable _ in the module's namespace for it to be identified?

Answer (score 3):

`gettext.install()` installs the inalterable one and only `_` into the builtins (module `__builtin__` or `builtins` in py3) - app-global. This way there is no flexibility.
Note: Python name resolution order is: locals > module-globals > builtins .

So anyway `gettext.translation()` (Class-based API) or even `gettext.GNUTranslations()` (e.g. for custom .mo path schemes) would be used explicitely for having multiple translations separately or mixed-style at the same time.

Some options:

- Via `t = gettext.translation(...); _ = t.ugettext` you could simply put separate translations as `_` into each module-global namespace - probably more automated way in real world. Just perhaps the main translation could still go into the builtins too (via `main_t.install()`).
- When a mix-all of all/many translations is ok or is what you want, you could chain several translations globally via `t.install(); t.add_fallback(t_plugin1); t.add_fallback(t_plugin1);...;`  - and preserve an app-global approach otherwise.
- gettext keywords other than _ could be used - and could be feed via the `xgettext -k other_keyword` option. But I'd dislike lengthy and module-unique names.
  ( Yet personally I prefer the keyword `I` generally over `_`,  and I also enable an operator scheme like `I % "some text"` instead of `_("some text")` or `I("some text")`. Via `I = t; t.__call__ = t.__mod__ = t.ugettext` effectively; plus a small patch of *pygettext.py*. This pattern is more pleasant for typing, looks more readable and Pythonic to me, and avoids the crucial/ugly name collision of `_` in Python with the interactive-last-result-anaphor (see `sys.displayhook`) when using gettext'ed modules on interactive Python prompts. `_` is also "reserved" as my preferred (local) placeholder for unused values in expressions like `_, _, x, y, z, _ = some_tuple`.
  After all `gettext` is a rather simple module & mechanism, and things are easily customizable in Python.)